# playa:child_ids parameters are not working

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

we have a big issue with the following code:

```
{event_related_media:child_ids limit="2" status="Archived" channel="video" show_expired="no" show_future_entries="no"}
```

With the following code, I get all the children entries id. None of the parameters are used to filter the results.

The official doc says explicitly that child_ids tag "supports almost all of {exp:channel:entries}’ tag parameters", but, well, no...

To be sure, I debug all SQL requests of the template, and whatever I used as channel name parameter (for instance, 'foo'), 'foo' is never used in any sql query.

Any idea?

Pv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s an error in the documentation, and we’ll get that fixed. `:child_ids` only supports filtering entries with the following parameters:

- var_id
- var
- element_id
- field_id
- field
- col_id
- col
- row_id
- child_id
- parent_id

If you need anything else, and you should just use a tag pair:

```
{event_related_media
    limit="2"
    status="Archived"
    channel="video"
    show_expired="no"
    show_future_entries="no"
    backspace="1"
}{entry_id}|{/event_related_media}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon, the workaround works well, even if the request is a bit slower.